# How to display category in main menu in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.5

```
Home
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
  ddd
  eee 
  fff
```

Actually in header menu home aaa bbb is display and other category under home menu is not display in header menu. Please suggest me to clear the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to modules and in the front office feature section find this module **" Top horizontal menu "** . Using this module configuration page, you can add any category, other links, products to the top menu.

In your case, the module has only those categories added to the top menu, thats why it is showing only those categories.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

go to module -> search for "Top horizontal menu" -> click on configure front of Top horizontal menu -> then add your category